# My apps can't connect to mysql, can you suggest things to test?

Tags: mysql, macos, localhost

I'm on a mac server. From my home directory, I can get to mysql on the command line. But apps I install (I've tried phpMyAdmin and then Wordpress) can't connect to mysql@localhost.

Suggestions on troubleshooting the problem?

Also, how can I tell what port mysql is running on?

Comment: When you connect from the command line, are you using the exact same credentials that you're trying to use with phpMyAdmin and Wordpress?

Comment: I am. I even created a user and granted him all possible access to everything and no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying 127.0.0.1:3306 as the host and see if that works...

*Edit from comments:*

> Use **`netstat -a`** to check which
>   port MySQL is listening on.

Comment: Does netstat -a indicate that it's listening on 3306?

Comment: netstat -a doesn't show port info on my Mac

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have the mysql extension installed.

More information: https://www.php.net/mysql

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have explicitly listed localhost when you granted permissions to the user. For example, if you have a database named blog which is accessed by a user named wordpress, you need to create the user with this:

```
grant all on blog.* to 'wordpress'@'localhost' identified by 'blahblah';
```

I believe that the mysql command-line utility uses Unix file sockets to connect, which bypasses any hostname or DNS restrictions.